# Angular - Binding a checkbox to an integer value in the data model

Tags: entity-framework, angularjs, checkbox, breeze

I have a SPA using Angular and Breeze using WebAPI against MS SQL.  In the data model booleans are represented as bit or integer.  As I bind a checkbox to the angular model I want two way binding where checked = 1 and unchecked = 0.  I understand the binding wants to work with strings.

I have looked at as many QAs here as I cand find on this topic but none seem exactly what I am looking for and I am also wondering if using Angular/Breeze/EF Pocos I should be changing something at the model level for what are essentially booleans so as to not "fight the framework".

This is also my first EF app.  If i have SQL bit columns and call them boolean in my poco classes will EF take care of the conversion to 0 or 1?

I have to assume this wheel has been invented over and over but I am still wrapping my head around Angular.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="haz.selected"  data-ng-true-value="1" data-ng-false-value="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is also my first EF app. If i have SQL bit columns and call them
>   boolean in my poco classes will EF take care of the conversion to 0 or
>   1?

EF will convert 0,1 to false,true respectively. If you serialize this value to angularjs. You just need to write:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="haz.selected" />
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should be able to define the column as boolean in the model and then Angular will be happy and EF will take care of the conversion.  I'll try it and report back.  Thanks

Comment: Changing data model to bool for values that will be bound to checkboxes fixes the problem for me.  I thought it might be worth thinking about that before trying to fight against the natural flow of Angular data binding.